# What is the best math library to use with java?

Tags: java, math

I want to use math functions for data mining and analytics purpose.
I need an opinion about a library that I can use for this purpose with java.
Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I would rephrase this as it is asking for opinions and therefore is open ended, argumentative.

Comment: Yes it is true. This is an open ended question.

Depending on my requirements I have decided to go for Apache Commons Math as they have almost all the functions that I would be using. Their other pluses are good documentation, great support from community plus its a project supported by Apache Foundation and when My 70% of libraries are from Apache , I am little biased towards them.

In Colt arena,I found multithreaded version of it , Parallel Colt quite interesting. I am just crossing my fingers now. I might do some performance analysis before I go further.

Answer (score 10):

There is [colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/).

> The Colt library provides fundamental general-purpose data structures optimized for numerical data, such as resizable arrays, dense and sparse matrices (multi-dimensional arrays), linear algebra, associative containers and buffer management.
>
> The Jet library contains mathematical and statistical tools for data analysis, powerful histogramming functionality, Random Number Generators and Distributions useful for (event) simulations, and more.
>
> The CoreJava library contains C-like print formatting. The Concurrent library contains standardized, efficient utility classes commonly encountered in parallel & concurrent programming.

Answer (score 5):

Apache Commons Math might be helpful.  So might JAMA.

UPDATE: In the 2.5 years since I last answered this, I've become aware of Apache's [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) and [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).  Both are excellent Java libraries for data analysis.

Both are more appropriate answers for the narrower concern of data mining.

Answer (score 3):

[JScience](http://jscience.org/) is certainly worth a look. Some examples involving rational arithmetic and unit conversion are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014747/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533782/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516237/230513).

Comment: I would also have recommended it.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Math

has got a lot of useful math functions.

Comment: Does the support datamining formula as well

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague but check out [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/).