# Using Java doubles (or anything else) to store simple fractions

Tags: java, math, floating-point, primitive-types

This seems like a very simple error:

```
double quarter = 1/4;
```

Is giving

```
0.0
```

Anybody know why this might be happening?

I am trying to store pretty much all the fractions from 1/2 to 1/20 (Just the ones with 1 on the top and in int on the bottom), so I won't be able to input the decimal straight away for all of them.

I've read and heard that *floating-point datatypes are not a good way of storing fractions*, so **is there any other way** (in Java)?

Comment: And to answer your second question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442640/is-there-a-commonly-used-rational-numbers-library-in-java suggests alternatives if you (as it sounds like) actually want rational numbers, rather than floating point division

Comment: And SO works best if you keep it to one question per post, for exactly this reason.

Comment: If you really want to retain that fraction/rational number character, without truncation, you should write a Fraction or Rational class that has numerator and denominator private members and all the methods you'd want to execute on it: add, sub, mul, div, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
double quarter = 1d/4d;
```

The division of two integers gives a truncated integer. By putting the `d` behind the numbers you are casting them to doubles.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, you're trying to divide `1/4` as integer values, and it's truncating it.  `1. / 4` will correctly give you `0.25`; other ways to express the number `1` as a `double` include `1d`, `1.0`, and so on.

Other approaches include:

- Use `BigDecimal` to store values to an exact decimal precision.  (For example, this is the preferred way to deal with monetary values.)
- Use a `Fraction` or `Rational` class, either rolling your own or using one from a library.  Apache Commons has [`Fraction`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html) and [`BigFraction`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/BigFraction.html), though their documentation seems a little sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

Java is performing integer division because your denominator is an integer.

Try the following:

```
double quarter = 1 / 4.0;
```

Or:

```
double quarter = 1 / (double) 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting 0.0 is because the division is done as an integer division and then the result is converted to float.  Try this, for example: `double quarter = 1.0/4.0;` - you should get (pretty much) the expected result.

However, depending on your requirements, this may not be the best way to deal with the problem.  For example, you can't store 1/3 in a decimal.  The perfect way would be to store simple fraction as a pair of integers.  You can create a class for it (with some arithmetic methods) or start by using a simple array.  It all depends on your needs.