# Java more precision in arithmetic

Tags: java, math, floating-accuracy

I am building a web app in Java that does math and shows steps to the user. When doing basic arithmetic with decimals I often get the messy in accurate outputs.

Here is my problem:

```
double a = 0.15;
double b = 0.01;
System.out.println(a - b);
// outputs 0.13999999999999999

float a = 0.15;
float b = 0.01;
System.out.println(a - b);
// outputs 0.14

float a = 0.16f;
float b = 0.01f;
System.out.println(a - b);
// outputs 0.14999999

double a = 0.16;
double b = 0.01;
System.out.println(a - b);
// outputs 0.15
```

Neither is reliable for `complete` accuracy. Is there a numeric class that is more precise or should I just round the values off?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: Won't work too well for 1/3, either.

Comment: You can use strictfp as well instead of BigDecimal. Explained at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java

Comment: strictfp is still floating-point, so that won't help (it will just ensure that all his users get the exact same messy results).

Comment: Can you use a link from Java 7 and provide an example of how this is done in BigDecimal?

Comment: The Sun/Oracle uses strictfp almost all the time so its unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: But the major point is that `strictfp` **reduces** your precision, if anything!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this. It's ugly, but it works:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.15");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.01");
System.out.println(a.subtract(b));
```

Be sure to construct them either with a String parameter, or with the `valueOf` method, like this:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("0.15");   // This is ok
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.15); // This is also ok
```

And not with a double parameter, like this:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(0.15); // DON'T DO THIS
```

Because if you pass in a double, you will also pass in double's inaccuracy into the new BigDecimal instance. If you pass in a String, BigDecimal will know™ and do the right thing™.

Comment: Instead of `new BigDecimal(0.15)` you should use `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.15)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're right, I missed that one. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Won't work too well for "1/3", though. For that you need rational numbers.

Comment: @Thilo True, but OP asked for "basic arithmetic with decimals", not for "basic arithmetic with rationals" :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply a sensible round when using `double`. If you do you can get 15 digits of accuracy which is more than enough in most cases.

```
double a = 0.15;
double b = 0.01;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", a - b);

double a2 = 0.16;
double b2 = 0.01;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", a2 - b2);
```

prints

```
0.14
0.15
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)?

Will not be completely accurate for all divisions, though (such as 1/3). For that you'd need fractions, which is not part of the JDK, but [easy to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442640/is-there-a-commonly-used-rational-numbers-library-in-java), for example as two integers (or BigIntegers).

Answer (score 0):

```
  BigDecimal  a = new BigDecimal(".15");
  BigDecimal  b = new BigDecimal(".01"),
  BigDecimal  c = new BigDecimal(0);

  c = a.subtract(b);      
  System.out.println(c);
```