# For Loop for Decimal values

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I'm getting two values like
a=2.7 (It can be anything in decimal for e.g 2.007 & ..)
b=3.5 (It can be anything in decimal for e.g 3.007 & ..)

**I want to extract all value between 2.7 to 3.5** i.e. **2.7, 2.8, 2.9  ........ 3.5**

The thing that I have tried is

```
for (double i = lower; i <= upper; i=i+0.1) {
    Storing i value;
            }
```

Where lower is starting decimal and upper is ending decimal value

How can I achieve this with for loop or any other method ?
Note : The value can be 2.7 OR 2.00007 as well

Comment: Works fine, what's the issue? https://ideone.com/wAatBQ

Comment: Worth noting that using boxed `Double` will result in a crazy amount of boxing and unboxing. Just use the primitive `double`.

Comment: @Michael Sorry typo mistake i'm using double
But what if value is lower = 3.789 and upper = 4.983 ?

Comment: @akshaykale, read this for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120311/why-does-adding-0-1-multiple-times-remain-lossless

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it your version *looks like* it should work.  However, I suspect you are running into a problem that is inherent in all computations that use `float` and `double`: floating point types are inexact<sup>1</sup>.

See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/)

(The answer is: No ... but it doesn't work how you think it does.)

Anyhow, with code like this:

```
for (double i = lower; i <= upper; i = i + 0.1) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

you might find that the values printed are not exactly what you expect.  Indeed, the last value (`upper` or thereabouts) may not be printed.  The root cause is floating point imprecision (as explained in the above Q&A).

If you want *exact* values to be printed all of the time you will need to use `BigDecimal` to represent the numbers and perform the arithmetic.

---

<sup>1 - This is not a Java specific problem.  You will see the same effect with any programming language that uses base-2 floating point representations for numbers.  Most modern computers have IEEE 754 compliant floating point arithmetic support in hardware, and most languages make use of this your their floating point types.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try by rounding off because up to **one decimal point**, this will work for you.

```
for (double i = lower; i <= upper; i += 0.1) 
        System.out.printf("%.1f\n",i);
```

You can find more about the problem without rounding off [Why does adding 0.1 multiple times remain lossless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120311/why-does-adding-0-1-multiple-times-remain-lossless)