# Why is there no BigDecimal.setPrecision() method?

Tags: java

Why is there a `BigDecimal.setScale()` method which sets the decimals to some value and no `MathContext.setScale()` method but only a constructor `MathContext(precision)` or other way around why is there no `BigDecimal.setPrecision()` method?

EDIT:
There is no method `MathContext.setPrecision()`, only a constructor `MathContext(precision)`. Edited the text. Sorry for that.

EDIT2:
I just wanted to understand why there are two ways of approaching a scale / precision setting. Seems there is no real reason to have two of them regarding the answer of Richard Sitze.

See this example which makes clear you can really have strange results playign with precision and scale:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("100.234", mc);
System.out.println("Scale: " + test.scale() + ", value: " + test);
test.setScale(6);
System.out.println("Scale: " + test.scale() + ", value: " + test);
test = test.add(new BigDecimal("100"));
System.out.println("Scale: " + test.scale() + ", value: " + test);
```

Results in:

```
Scale: -1, value: 1.0E+2
Scale: -1, value: 1.0E+2
Scale: 0, value: 200
```

The results are correct regarding the settings but when I set the scale to 6 I expect a warning / hint / exception which says that the precision settings do not allow a scale of 6.

Comment: You'll have to ask whoever wrote `BigDecimal`.

Comment: What particular problem are you trying to solve by asking this question?

Comment: @SteveP. The precision can be set as a MathContext constructor argument. A MathContext is immutable, so no setXXX methods at all.

Comment: @Steve P: You are right Steve, you can only pass the precision in the constructor but the problem remains the same :)

Comment: @4thfloorstudios What problem?  There is no problem.

Comment: Because [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is immutable.

Comment: @ColinD: I want to be able to create a MathContext to pass to a BigDecimal and I wondered what happens if i pass a MathContext with precision 3 and scale value of 10 to the constructor `BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale, MathContext mc)` The question is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107162/maximum-precision-below-unlimited)

Comment: Can't you use [`round(MathContext mc)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round(java.math.MathContext))

Comment: @4thfloorstudios You should include all of that in your question. As is, your questions looks like you are asking about designer choices which is off topic.

Comment: @4thfloorstudios If that was actually your question, then you shouldn't have asked the question that you did.  See the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).   Additionally, these are two completely different questions.  One is somewhat subjective, and potentially closeable, and the other is clearly acceptable, and much more likely to get you the answer that you actually want.

Comment: @all: I must apologize for the way I asked the question. If you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107162/maximum-precision-below-unlimited) you will understand what I mean (hopefully).

Comment: Honestly, from the comments, I'm still a little confused about your confusion.  I suggest that you create an entirely new question that details exactly what you're trying to do in words, and with accompanying code.

Comment: @SteveP: Will do that, thanks for your time!

Comment: @4thfloorstudios Also, it's a good idea to reference other posts in your question, if applicable.  It helps people to understand your problem, and lowers the possibility of it being closed as a duplicate if the questions are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The powers-that-be declared that the overall *precision* (total # of digits) can be adjusted only incidentally by changing the *scale* (# of digits to the right of the decimal point).

This is appropriate, as any change to precision necessitates a change to scale.
So at best `setPrecision` is redundant;
having only `setScale` has resulted in a cleaner API.

Now consider a change to precision and how the result might need to be rounded.
In going through that analysis,
you will consider "how many digits should remain after rounding".
That **is** the scale.
Thus any such consideration leads back to the question of how the scale
should be changed.

`setScale` with its variants to specify rounding are a natural fit.
Less so for a hypothetical `setPrecision`, which begs for code comments to fill the gap (IMHO).

Answer (score 3):

There is no method `MathContext.setPrecision()`, only a non-static `getPrecision()`.  The constructor for `MathContext`is what is used to set the precision.

If you refer to the documentation of `BigDecimal`, we have:

> The BigDecimal class gives its user complete control over rounding
>   behavior. If no rounding mode is specified and the exact result cannot
>   be represented, an exception is thrown; otherwise, calculations can be
>   carried out to a chosen precision and rounding mode by supplying an
>   appropriate MathContext object to the operation.

Essentially, there's no reason to recreate the wheel--`MathContext` already does this, by design.