# How can I change string or int into a Rational?

Tags: java, numbers, rational-number

Here is the code,

```
         System.out.print("Enter r1: ");
         r1 =  in.next();
         System.out.print("Enter r2");
         r2 = in.next();
         System.out.println(myR.addR(r1,r2));
```

r1 and r2 is initialize as `Rational`.
Here is my question,
How can I change `r1=in.next` (which is in string form)into a rational form? Can I write `r1 = in.Rational` ....any tips plzzz

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5442640/230513).

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40561 see this link

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to solve.

Instead of `r1 = in.next();`, use `r1 = in.nextInt()` or `r1 = in.nextDouble()`, depending on which kind of number you want.

Comment: It won't work. none of it work(int, Line, double), it says required