# How to get from 10.0/3*3 BigDecimal and double?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

```
double a = 10.0;
double b =3; 
double c = a/b;
System.out.println(c*b);//answer = 10.0

BigDecimal bigDecimal1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(c);
BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal("3");
System.out.println(bigDecimal1.multiply(bigDecimal2));//answer = 10.0000000000000005
```

I'm trying to make a calculator, but there's a problem with 10/3*3
I don't want to just calculate 10/3*3 this formula, I want to return this formula plus 0.2323232323232 of the float. So use the BigDecimal class. There's something wrong with it
I couldn't get the exact result, that's what I wanted 10,
Rather than get 10.0000000000000005

Comment: `There's something wrong with it I couldn't get the exact result, that's what I wanted 10, and got 10` So, where is the problem?

Comment: sorry,I want to get 10(only used BigDecimal)

Comment: The core problem is that there is no decimal or binary fraction that is exactly equal to 10/3. You can get arbitrary close in BigDecimal, but not be exact. If you need exact representation of arbitrary fractions, you need a rational number package.

Comment: Is there no ready-made class library?

Comment: Last time I checked, my calculator could not represent 10.0 / 3 exactly either.  Unfortunate finite floating-point representations are broken.  What you really need is an infinite representation, and a machine with infinite memory to hold it ......... :-)

Comment: @Stephen C I think try trying to catch exceptions（ArithmeticException）
This method   divide
public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor)  Maybe it can solve the problem.

Comment: Nope.   What you are running up against here is **Mathematics**.  There is no finite floating point representation for  10.0 / 3 in either base 10 or base 2.

Comment: Well, you're right to follow your logic. Your serious (mathematics) makes me lol  (my English-- machine translation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem may be here

```
double c = a/b;
...
BigDecimal bigDecimal1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(c);
```

You're expecting that a double can *perfectly* represent 10/3, and I doubt it can

Maybe try something like this, which always represents numbers as `BigDecimal`

```
new BigDecimal("10").divide(new BigDecimal("3"))
```

At which point you'll notice that 10/3 is not representable as a decimal

`Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result`

You need to decide how much precision you want, and then use rounding

```
new BigDecimal("10")
    .setScale(10)
    .divide(new BigDecimal("3"), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
```

Or you could use a rational number library, as suggested by Patricia. Perhaps see [Is there a commonly used rational numbers library in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5442640/134894)

Comment: System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10").setScale(10).divide(new BigDecimal("3"), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).multiply(new BigDecimal("3")));  i dont get 10  ,I get  9.9999999999   
Is there any solution?

Comment: @WeFUN The solution to needing exact, not just closely approximate, representation of arbitrary fractions is to use a rational number package.