# How to achieve "1 - 1/3 - 1/3 - 1/3 = 0"?

Tags: java, math, rational-numbers

I want to be able to subtract 1/3 from my variable in a mathematically correct way, meaning: If a 1D is subtracted by 1/3 three times, it should be 0D.

However, I keep ending up with some tiny value (1.1102230246251565E-16)

I've already tried rounding it after each subtraction (Math.round(input*1000000.0)/1000000.0), however I end up with 0.333334 after the second subtraction, and with 1.0E-6 after the third subtraction. Why?

Comment: See also the classic https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3001761

Comment: round the result up. Use round function

Comment: There is no finite representation of 1/3 as double. And double has only a limit number of digits.

Comment: how do I round up/down dynamically, based on the x-th decimal-point?

Comment: That is a different question.  Ask it as a different Question, and be sure to express yourself more clearly than that.  (What do you actually mean by "round up/down dynamically, based on the x-th decimal-point" ... bearing in mind that `float` and `double` are not "decimal" representations.

Comment: You could also have a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5442640/3545273) if you are interested in doing *exact* operations on rational numbers.

Comment: If you want exact arithmetic for arbitrary rational numbers then you need to use a Rational class. float and double won't do it, and neither will BigDecimal.