# Is there a way to make JScience output in a more "human friendly" format?

Tags: java, jscience

When I use toString() for JScience Amount objects I get results like this:

```
(7.5 ± 4.4E-16) mph
```

This isn't awful, but I'd really like it to output something like:

```
7.5 miles per hour
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

*edit:* Just to clarify, I'm hoping for a solution that will work for any Amount with any type of Units (or at least all of the pre-defined ones), not just "mph".

Comment: Have you tried setting your own format on org.jscience.physics.amount.AmountFormat?

Comment: @Roger I have not, is there a way to do what I need in a general way with it?

Comment: It seems fairly easy to set a static amount format. The javadoc even has an example. See http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/physics/amount/AmountFormat.htmlMaybe the getExactDigitsInstance is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it discards the errors and units, you can do something like this:

```
Amount<Velocity> x = Amount.valueOf(7.5, NonSI.MILES_PER_HOUR);
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(
    x.doubleValue(NonSI.MILES_PER_HOUR) + " miles per hour");
```

Console:

```
(7.5 ± 4.4E-16) mph
7.5 miles per hour
```

Addendum: *I'm hoping for a solution that works for any amount with any units.*

You'll still have to provide your own label to replace the default [`UnitFormat`](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/UnitFormat.html#label%28javax.measure.unit.Unit,%20java.lang.String%29); the label characters are limited by `isValidIdentifier()`. You can also substitute your own [`AmountFormat`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/physics/amount/AmountFormat.html), as suggested by @Roger Lindsjö. This example prints an arbitrary number of significant digits of the estimated value and a valid variation of your label. See also [`TypeFormat`](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/text/TypeFormat.html).

```
final UnitFormat uf = UnitFormat.getInstance();
uf.label(NonSI.MILES_PER_HOUR, "miles_per_hour");
AmountFormat.setInstance(new AmountFormat() {

    @Override
    public Appendable format(Amount<?> m, Appendable a) throws IOException {
        TypeFormat.format(m.getEstimatedValue(), -1, false, false, a);
        a.append(" ");
        return uf.format(m.getUnit(), a);
    }

    @Override
    public Amount<?> parse(CharSequence csq, Cursor c) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parsing not supported.");
    }
});
Amount<Velocity> x = Amount.valueOf(7.5, NonSI.MILES_PER_HOUR);
System.out.println(x);
```

Console:

```
7.5 miles_per_hour
```

Comment: Right, however I'm hoping for a solution that works for any amount with any units, mph was just an example