# JScience formatting fractions

Tags: jscience

is there an easy way to format numbers as fractions.

if user inputs "1/4in into a INCH unit value, i would like to see "1/4" instead of .25, 1/3 instead of .333333 etc..

sort of like an alias for certain select values.

is this something i can do globally in MeasureFormat?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct instances of `org.jscience.mathematics.number.Rational`; it's implementation of `toText()`, invoked by `Number#toString()`, may be all you need. If not, more on `AmountFormat` may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516237/230513).

```
Rational a = Rational.valueOf(1, 4);
Rational b = Rational.valueOf(1, 3);
```