# Convert Ada Union type to Object class in Java

Tags: java, ada

The picture below is an `Ada` Union type (Figure).

How can I convert this Union type from Ada to Object in Java? Please help me.

**This is the code**

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please post code, rather than pictures of code. Consider a Java `class` having attributes such as `java.lang.Boolean`, `java.awt.Color`, `java.awt.Shape`, etc.  Then, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: You also want to be a bit more specific about what you are wanting to do.  The Ada example you are providing is not a Union, which is very different in function from a variant record (which is what you are showing).  You can emulate some aspects of a variant record in Java, but it would be important to know what functionality specifically you want to emulate in Java that the Ada example provides you.

Comment: The image appears to be an excerpt from [CS 354](http://cs.boisestate.edu/~buff/syllabi/cs354-1f14.pdf), a lecture of which examines [design issues](http://cs.boisestate.edu/~alark/cs354/lectures/records_unions.pdf) with traditional unions.

Comment: Completly off-topic of the OP, the second @trashgod links states at the end "With structural type equivalence, you cannot differentiate between types of the same structure (*e.g. different units of speed, both float*)". Ada 2012 or higher provides a very nice feature which I would call "dimension analysis". Basically, it allows to define both *units* and a mapped numerical type. Ada toolchain would then have a compile/exec time type *and* unit solving. A better overview here https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-136-how-tall-is-a-kilogram

Comment: See also [_Converting different unit types in JScience library_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44407365/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I have doubts concerning the canonical way to designate such Ada records ('unions'), I always used 'variant record' or 'discriminant record'.

According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/record#Union `Union` in an Ada context refers to variant record declaration + C convention union.

This is enforced by [ARM §B.3.3](http://ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-B-3-3.html), quoting:

> Specifying aspect `Unchecked_Union` to have the value `True` defines an interface correspondence between a given **discriminated type** and **some C union**.
>   EDIT: The aspect requires that the associated type shall be given a representation that allocates *no space for its discriminant(s)*.

```
type T (Flag : Boolean := False) is
   record
       case Flag is
           when False =>
               F1 : Float := 0.0;
           when True =>
               F2 : Integer := 0;
       end case;
    end record
    with Unchecked_Union;
32/2
X : T;
Y : Integer := X.F2; -- erroneous
```

Quoting [ARM § 3.8.1](http://ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-8-1.html#S0072), the OP record declaration is NOT an union.

> Example of record type with a variant part:

```
type Device is (Printer, Disk, Drum);
type State  is (Open, Closed);
type Peripheral(Unit : Device := Disk) is
   record
      Status : State;
      case Unit is
         when Printer =>
            Line_Count : Integer range 1 .. Page_Size;
         when others =>
            Cylinder   : Cylinder_Index;
            Track      : Track_Number;
         end case;
      end record;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a hit on space and implementing this by defining enums and then adding all the fields to the same object.

```
class Figure {
    public enum Shape { Circle, Triangle, Rectangle };
    public enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue };
    Shape form;
    boolean Filled;
    Colors color;
    float Diameter;
    int Leftside, Rightside;
    float Angle;
    int Side1, Side2;
}
```

operations on the object just need to check the value of 'form' to know which fields they should consider, and which fields to ignore.

Now that you've translated the *idea* (however roughly) to Java, you can apply your knowledge of Java to iterate on the idea.

Comment: You might consider also making the member variables that correspond to the ones in the case statement in the Ada version to be private and use getters/setters to enforce the discriminant check.  Though it all depends on the OP's actual requirements, which haven't been updated.